# Vscode prettier adding curly braces on saving react code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

on saving my react code on vscode, `prettier` is not formatting properly.  And somehow it is adding { " " } on 4th and 5th line. Has someone faced any issue like that earlier?

```
function topHeader() {
    return ( <
        div className = "Header" >
        Header { " " } <
        button className = "button button--newthread" > Start a new Thread < /button>{" "} <
        /div>
    );
}
export default topHeader;
```